# Do I use "some", "an" or "a" for "slice of apple"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, determiners, quantifiers

If we cut an apple into two slices, what should we say?

> an apple.

or

> some apple

[image: Apple with segment cut out]

Comment: Usually, you say a slice of cake,  a slice of lemon, a slice of apple, etc.

Comment: no, my question is that which one is correct? an apple or some apple. I don't know to use which one. some or an?

Comment: an apple is more common and idiomatic.

Comment: @khan even if it cut into two slices?

Comment: You should give a sentence or a situation where you are going to use it.

Answer (score 2):

**some apple** (singular) : the apple has been *diced*  (or some apples have been diced) and the chopped fruit is not countable

**some apple slices** : slices of apple

**an apple** : a single whole apple

**half (of) an apple** : one half of an apple

**an apple halved**:   an apple cut into two equal pieces

**an apple quartered**: an apple cut into four equal pieces

Your picture shows an image for which there is no precise word.  We would have to say something like "An apple with a quarter (of it) cut out".

Comment: Also, "some apple" could be used when you just want some apple, without being specific about one, one-and-a-half, just a half, etc. Your emphasis on _diced_ above implies that this is required to use "some apple". Perhaps add "has been, for example, _diced_"?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree, John.  If there are a bowl of whole apples, one wouldn't ask for "*some* apple".  The word "some" requires the apples to be cut in some manner, so that they can be referred to as an uncountable. If people are sitting around a table and adding various ingredients to their own salads, say, and there  happen to be some sliced apples in a bowl on or a plate, one might say "Please pass the apple" and thereby refer to the apple slices as one of the salad ingredients, but "Please pass the *apples*" is far more likely, IMO, even though they have been sliced.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is the image of an apple cut **into half**.

There are **two apple halves**, or **two halves** of an apple. (They mean exactly the same)
We can count the number of apple pieces.
A person might ask for **half an apple**.

[image]

This is a picture of **some apple slices.**
We can also say **some sliced apples**, if we know more than one apple has been sliced.
It's not easy to count all the slices, so it's just quicker to say *some*.
You could also ask for **some apple** if you wanted more than two slices or pieces.

[image]

This is a picture of a single apple and **a quarter slice**.  As you can see, the apple is not cut into two slices. 
The apple has not been cut **into four quarters**. (Alternatively) It has not been **quartered**.
Although we can see it is countable, some people might ask for **some apple**, or ask for the **larger/smaller piece**.

> **[slice](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slice)**
>    a flat, often thin, piece of food that has been cut from a larger piece:
>   *cucumber/lemon slices*
>   *Layer the pasta with slices of tomato.*
>    *Could you cut me a smaller slice?*
>
> **[quarter](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quarter)** (noun)
>   one of four equal or almost equal parts of something; ¼:
>   *He cut the orange into quarters.*
>
> **[quarter](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quarter?q=quartered)** (verb)
>   [ Transitive; often passive ] to cut something into four parts
>   to divide something into four pieces of approximately the same size:
>   *Peel and quarter the tomatoes and put them in the stew.*
>   <sub><sup>**Cambridge Dictionary**</sup></sub>